# Syntax for these two SQL Queries in cursor.execute() when I have a variable (%variable) from my python code in each query?

Tags: python, sql, syntax

I'm doing a python program using impala for sql. I'm connecting to a database and I've been running a list of queries. The first thing I did was to take elements from the original database and store it into a python list, where I assigned elements of the list into variables `(variable1, variable2)`. I'm able to reference variables from my python code in my SQL query when it's just one line, but I'm having trouble regarding joining the syntax of both of these queries via union, which I need to do for my next step. What is the syntax for joining the queries (as shown below) together? I'm trying to figure out the syntax for a union.

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * from database where database.variable = '%str'"%variable1)

 cursor.execute("SELECT * from database where database.variable = '%str'"%variable2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use variables in your SQL queries. The variable itself should be a tuple.

```
sql = "SELECT * from database where database.variable = %s"
prepared_variable = (variable1, ) # tuple
cursor.execute(sql, prepared_variable)
```

Comment: What's the syntax for the query you wrote to be database.variable = variable1 OR two? As in, having two variables as tuples?